# How do i save json Object to Assets folder using LocalStorage

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app

I serialized a data from the net to Json and i want to save it to a path in the application folder "Assets" how do i do it with Local Storage? or is IsolatedStorage the right option to use?

```
string js = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(up, Formatting.Indented);
StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile textFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("upcoming.Json", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
using (IRandomAccessStream textStream = await textFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    using (DataWriter textWriter = new DataWriter(textStream))
    {
        textWriter.WriteString(js);
        await textWriter.StoreAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to write to the assets folder, but you can write to the LocalStorage, RoamingStorage (synced across devices) or TemporaryStorage. Those storages are only accessible for your apps.

Below is a link to a guide with sample to help you on your way.
http://jamescroft.co.uk/blog/uwp/how-to-implement-local-storage-in-universal-windows-apps/

Comment: So there is no way i can write to Assets even with IsolatedStorage?

Comment: The assetsfolder is in a sandboxed environment that you only have readaccess to.

Comment: I just have to know the file name to use it... the part is fixed I guess